# Android Custom font in Custom ExpandableListAdapter

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I am trying to use custom typeface in a custom expandable listview. However, when I try to do this, initially, the text and the typeface are not visible for the ExpandableListView, when the Viewpager fragment(which I use) loads.

Once I click on the blank text in the expandable listview, the text and the font shows up. This problem seems to occur only for the custom typeface. If I use any other custom feature like change the color etc. for the textview, it works well. Kindly help

Please see the attached images for further reference:
[image: 1]
[image: 2]

Relevant portion of my code for custom expandable listadapter:

```
public class MyExpandableListAdapter extends SimpleExpandableListAdapter {

    View cntView;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    Context cxt;
    TextView tvGrp, tvChild;

    public MyExpandableListAdapter(Context context,
            List<? extends Map<String, ?>> groupData, int groupLayout,
            String[] groupFrom, int[] groupTo,
            List<? extends List<? extends Map<String, ?>>> childData,
            int childLayout, String[] childFrom, int[] childTo) {
        super(context, groupData, groupLayout, groupFrom, groupTo, childData,
                childLayout, childFrom, childTo);
        cxt=context;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        super.getGroupView(groupPosition, isExpanded, convertView, parent);
        View tmp;


        if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            tmp=new View(cxt);
            inflater=(LayoutInflater)cxt.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            tmp=inflater.inflate(R.layout.explistgroup, null);
        }else{
            tmp = (View)convertView;
        }

        tvGrp=(TextView) tmp.findViewById(R.id.rowTextView);
        tvGrp.setTypeface(FontLoader.loadTypeface(cxt,R.raw.roboto_regular));  // This does not work. It shows a blank textview initially. Only after I click it, the typeface and the text come into effect
        //tvGrp.setText("ambit"); -- This works well

        return tmp;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to load custom font from assets, for example:

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "<your font name>.ttf");
tvGrp.setTypeface(tf);
```

Comment: Thanks Natali, but that did not help me. I am getting the same problem :(. Please let me know if you can think of any other way to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

OK here is a thing you need to do:
1- Initialize a public static variable in the Activity from where you are using the custom adapter for your expandable listview say MainListActivity like this:

`public static Typeface typeFace;`

2- Now initialize it like Natali mentioned in the same Activity like this:

`tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "<your font name>.ttf");`

3- Now use the following in your custom adapter as directed by Mr. Natali but with a slight change

`tvGrp.setTypeface(MainListActivity.typeFace);`

If the problem persists also try to extend the custom adapter class with `BaseExpandableListAdapter`

Answer (score 0):

You only create a view, not set text to it. Is there `text` in xml?
I think this method should be like this:

```
@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
        View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewGroup tmp = (ViewGroup)super.getGroupView(groupPosition, isExpanded, convertView, parent);
    tvGrp=(TextView) tmp.findViewById(R.id.rowTextView);
    tvGrp.setTypeface(FontLoader.loadTypeface(cxt,R.raw.roboto_regular));  // This does not work. It shows a blank textview initially. Only after I click it, the typeface and the text come into effect
    //tvGrp.setText("ambit"); -- This works well

    return tmp;

}
```

Or your creating and initializing instead of calling super.

And this should work properly.